# Finding the connected components of $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{\langle 0, 0 \rangle\}$

Tags: general-topology

> Find the connected components of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{( 0, 0 )\}$

I'm trying to think up of examples to solidify my understanding of connected components of topological spaces. This was a question I came up with, but I'm having trouble answering it.

Now $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{( 0, 0 )\}$ must have the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I was thinking that there would be four cases if we pick $(x, y ) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{( 0, 0 )\}$, where each case would be if $( x, y )$ lied in a different quadrant of the plane, however the problem with that was that the union of the equivalence classes would not equal the whole space $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{( 0, 0 )\}$

How could I go about finding the connected components of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{( 0, 0 )\}$?

Comment: It suffices to show that the space is path-connected, and one can describe without much trouble an explicit path between two arbitrary points.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0,0\}$ is its own connected component. The space is path-connected and will hence be connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is connected, since it is path-connected. So, it has a single connected component.